# C fopen/fwrite driving me to madness - fwrite not writing

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite

Ok, here is the deal...i remember creating a program past week that required me to open a file in binary mode and write data to it. At first, i tried using the fopen function, checking if the result is ok, then try to write data. I remember that at first try, the fwrite operation wasn't working. Then, after moving declaration of variables from a place to another, i was finally able to make the fwrite to insert data to the file.

Now, i need to create another similar program to do some other stuff, so i wanted to use the same allocation code (actually, i wanted to create a specific function to do the same), and here is what i was able to come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                        

int openfile(FILE *main, char *name, int option);    

int main(void)                                            
{                                                         

  FILE *main;                                        
  int header_init;                                        
  int result;                                             

  switch (openfile(main,"main_file.bin",1)) {
    case 1:                                               
      header_init = -1;                                   
      //fseek(main,0,SEEK_SET);    --> useless
      fwrite(&header_init,sizeof(int),1,main);       
      printf("ftell = %d\n",ftell(main)); break;     
    case 2:                                               
      fread(&header_init,sizeof(int),1,main);        
      printf("%d\n",header_init); break;                  
    default:                                              
      printf("Error trying to open file\n");                  
  }                                                       
  printf("header_init is %d\n",header_init);              
  fclose(main); exit(0);                             
}                                                         

int openfile(FILE *main, char *name, int option)      
{                                                         
  int result_alloc;                                       
  int F_OK;                                               
  if (result_alloc = access (name, F_OK) != 0) {          
    printf("File not found, allocating a new one\n");    
    if ((main= fopen(name,"w+b")) != NULL) return 1;
  }                                                       
  else {                                                  
    printf("File exist, allocating as r+b\n");    
    if ((main= fopen(name,"r+b")) != NULL) return 2;
  }                                           
  printf("Failure trying to open"); 
  return 0;                                   
}
```

For some unfortunate reason, the fwrite operation is not writing -1 to the allocated file. My intention with this program is so that it will always check for existence of that specific file: if there is one in place, simply open it with r+b to allow update functions without overwriting the actual file contents. Otherwise, allocate a new one with a header value of -1 (i will use this file as a record file with chained list structure).

Seriously, i cannot understand why this is not working. The idea is the same of my previous program. The only thing that changed is that i created a function, because this is going to happen me later (because of the 3rd parameter that will allow me to reduce my code and make it more "readable" - at least this is the intention!). I HAVE to admit that i have some attention to details problem, but i am working hard to get better at it, i am probably missing something stupid in this code, but after hours looking at it i really wanted to ask here for some help. Thanks

Edit: I am running it under z/Linux. What i am trying to understand is, why the code above doesn't write -1 to the file, but the one below writes ok?

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                 
int main(void)                                                     
{                                                                  
  FILE *main;                                                      
  int result_alloc;                                                
  int header_init;                                                 
  int F_OK;                                                        

  if (result_alloc = access ("test.bin", F_OK) != 0) {             
    printf("File not found, allocating a new one\n");              
    if ((main = fopen("test.bin","w+b")) == NULL) {                
      printf("Failure trying to open file");                       
      return 1;                                                    
    }                                                              
    else {                                                         
      header_init = -1;                                            
      printf("current pos is: w+b %d\n",ftell(main));              
      fwrite(&header_init,sizeof(int),1,main);                     
      printf("current pos is: write header_init %d\n",ftell(main));
    }                                                              
  }                                                                
  else {                                                           
    if ((main = fopen("test.bin","r+b")) == NULL) {                
      printf("Failure trying to open file");                       
      return 2;                                                    
    }                                                              
    else {                                                         
      printf("current pos is: r+b %d\n",ftell(main));              
      fread(&header_init,sizeof(int),1,main);                      
      printf("current pos is: read header_init %d\n",ftell(main)); 
    }                                                              
  }                                                                
}
```

Comment: C is pass-by-value. Changing a function parameter in the callee doesn't change the corresponding argument in the caller. Also, you *really* need to go back to basics: `int F_OK; /**/ access (name, F_OK);` doesn't do what you think it does. *Do* enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @EOF is right : the right prototype of function `openfile()` is `openfile(FILE **main, char *name, int option)`. It must be called by `openfile(&main,"main_file.bin",1)`

Comment: You want to learn how to use a debugger, tracing your code step by step and in between inspecting the values of all relevant variable. This way you can observe in detail what is going on and there is no need any more to dig around in the dark.

Comment: I admit that i lack the skill to use gdb debugger and need to learn it asap. I admit too that it sucks to keep printing stuff to "try to debug" (it is too much work). About the access function, i found the example at http://pubs.opengroup.org/ site (there is an example there saying about "test existence of a file"), so i thought that would be ok (it actually worked as expected in the previous code.

Comment: To add up to *EOF* and *francis*: ... and inside `openfile()` replace all occurrences of `main` by `(*main)`.

Comment: You are on which platform with this code?

Comment: Turn all warnings on when compiling by specifying the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` then fix the code until no more warnings are issued during compilation. Do not type-cast to silence the compiler.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to declare a variable name that is the same as a function name.  and your variable 'main' is actually a pointer to a file descriptor.   A common way of naming such a pointer is `fp` or perhaps `fp_out`, etc.

Comment: Suggest reading the man page for `access()`.   then use the right parameters;  I.E. result = access( filename, F_OK );  where F_OK is a macro defined in a header file (must #include that header file. typically `#include <unistd.h>`)

Comment: it is good programming practice to check for errors.  In this case, the returned value from fwrite() should be the same as the `nmemb` parameter otherwise an error has occurred

Comment: the `option` parameter to the openfile() function is not used.   The value of that parameter should be `F_OK`, not 1 and that should be the second parameter to the access() function

Comment: multiple `return` statements is poor programming practice.  instead of multiple `return` statements, set a local variable and return the local variable. I.E.  `int ret;  ... ret = 1; ... ret = 2; ... ret = 0; ... return ret;`

Comment: Note: `access()` does not check if the file exists, rather it checks if the 'real' user has permission to read/write/etc the file.   What should be used is: `stat()` as that will return an error if the file does not exist or cannot be accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that the assignment to the `main` variable inside of the `openfile` function is not seen by the calling function.  Because C is pass by value, you're only changing the value of the function parameter, not the value of the variable that was passed in.  So when `openfile` returns, the `main` variable inside of the `main` function is unchanged.

What you need to do is pass the **address** of that variable to the function, then within the function you dereference the local variable (which is a pointer) and assign a value to the dereferenced variable.

Also, it's not a good idea to have a variable with the same name as a function as it hides the function in that scope and can cause confusion.

So you would define your function as follows:

```
int openfile(FILE **fp, char *name, int option);
```

You would then call it like this (changing the name of the `main` variable to `fp`):

```
FILE *fp;
...
openfile(&fp,"main_file.bin",1)
```

Then inside of `openfile`, you dereference `fp` to change the value in the calling function:

```
*fp = fopen(name,"w+b")
```

The reason why the second code sample is working is that you're assigning directly to a local variable and then using that same variable later on in the function.

Also, you're "lucky" that the second piece of code is working because you did this:

```
int F_OK;
```

`F_OK` is already defined in unistd.h, where `access()` is defined.  So by doing this you're redeclaring it and not giving it a value, causing undefined behavior.  Get rid of this definition, and `#include <unistd.h>`, and the call to `access()` is guaranteed to work as expected.

Comment: Nailed it !!! Now i get it. I am sorry if this was a beginner question, but i really wanted to hear from someone. This last response just solved my problem and taught me a few things. Of course the other comments were also good, i know i am not really good with C, but hopefully i will become an expert (someday!). Now it is working fine! I wanted to do this change by defining a function to get used to this type of thing, my previous code need a lot of functions to help with readability, and these answers definitively helped me. Thanks all !!!